# Передача динамических матриц в функцию

Tags: c++

Есть три матрицы разных размеров. Есть функция, в которою передаётся одна из матриц

```
void input(int **mat);
```

Три матрицы, у каждой есть количество строк и количество столбцов, в общей сумме 6 значений. Не хочу создавать 6 переменных, которые будут отвечать за размерность, но для работы с матрицами в функции нужно знать размер
Какой есть более экономный вариант?
P.S.: без использования структур

Comment: А кроме структур всё остальное это костыли. Классы ещё разве что.

Comment: В порядке бреда - матрица, в которой первая строка не данных, а служебная, и содержит размеры матрицы :)

Comment: А если матрица, скажем, `double` или один элемент в строке?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, создать массив из шести элементов, где будете хранить значения строк и колонок матриц. И к нему можно объявить переисление.

Например,

```
enum { n1 = 0, n2 = 2, n3 = 4 };

int dim[6];
```

И обращаться к элементам массива

```
void input( int **mat, const int *dim, int n )
{
    int rows = dim[n];
    int cols = dim[n+1];

    //

    for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            //...
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Соответственно вызывать эту функцию можете как

```
input( mat1, dim, n1 );
```